# Getting Error regarding :Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, chart.js

I don't know why its giving length `undefiined` and other one is `setDailyData` is not a function

```
const Charts = () => {
  const { setDailyData, dailyData } = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
    };
    console.log(dailyData);

    fetchAPI();
  }, []);
```

Here I'm trying to get the data from `dailyData` and using a ternary ops to check if there is any data then  display the chart 
 if not,(by checking the length of the array) it should show `null`

Even making it `dailyData[0]` I gives error cannot read '0' property.

```
const lineChart =
 ( dailyData.length ?(
    <Line
      data={{
        labels: dailyData.map(({ date }) => date),
        datasets: [
          {
            data: dailyData.map(({ confirmed }) => confirmed),
            label: "Infected",
            borderColor: "#3333ff",
            fill: true,
          },
          {
            data: dailyData.map(({ deaths }) => deaths),
            label: "Deaths",
            borderColor: "#3333ff",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
            fill: true,
          },
        ],
      }}
    />
  ):null
)
```

API code to fetch the data for charts

```
export const fetchDailyData = async ()=>{
    try {
        const {data} = await axios.get(`${url}/daily`);

        const modifiedData = data.map((dailyData) =>({
            confirmed:dailyData.confirmed.total,
            deaths:dailyData.deaths.total,
            date:dailyData.reportDate
        }));
        console.log(data);

        return modifiedData;

    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState return an array, not an object

From your code

```js
const Charts = () => {
  // const { setDailyData, dailyData } = useState([]);
  const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]) // <-- change to this

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());
    };
    console.log(dailyData);

    fetchAPI();
  }, []);
```